# what is the norm of this linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis

$l:C[0,\pi]\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $l(f)=\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)\sin^2(x) dx$

I need to find the norm of $l$,

$|l|\le \int_{0}^{\pi}|f| dx$ as $|\sin^2 x|\le 1$
but I am not able to proceed further step. Thanks for help.

$\|l\|=\sup_{\|f\|=1}\{|l(f)|\}$ right? in that case $\|l\|=\pi ?$

Comment: Do you want to find the norm or bound it from above?

Comment: Just a quick remark, you can put a lot of norm on the space $C(0,\pi)$, it may be useful to say which one you're considering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

$$\lvert l(f)\rvert = \left\lvert \int_0^\pi f(x)\sin^2 x\,dx\right\rvert \leqslant \int_0^\pi \lvert f(x)\rvert \sin^2 x\, dx \leqslant \lVert f\rVert \int_0^\pi \sin^2 x\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\lVert f\rVert.$$

When can equality hold in each of the inequalities?

Comment: so $\|l\|=\sup\{|l(f)|:\|f\|=1\} ={\pi\over 2}$ right?

Comment: Right. You have equality whenever $f$ is constant.